# Why integrand of $V_1$ is constructed as a scalar $(3.6.14)$ for $\mu,\nu$ indicies in Polchinski

Tags: symmetry, string-theory, tensor-calculus, conformal-field-theory

When doing Polyakov treatment of vertex operator of first excited state using diff-invariance symmetry Polchinski comes with following:
$$V_1=\frac{g_c}{\alpha'}\int d^2\sigma \hspace{2pt}g^{1/2}\bigg\{\Big(g^{ab}\color{red}{s_{\mu\nu}}+i{\epsilon^{ab}}\color{red}{a_{\mu\nu}}\Big)\Big[\partial_aX^{\mu}\partial_bX^{\mu}e^{ik\cdot X}\Big]_r+\alpha'\phi R\Big[e^{ik\cdot X}\Big]_r\bigg\}$$
where $[\hspace{2pt}]_r$ is normal ordering in curved spacetime i.e. $$[F]_r=\exp\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\int d^2\sigma \hspace{2pt} d^2\sigma'\Delta(\sigma,\sigma')\frac{\delta}{\delta X^{\mu}(\sigma)}\frac{\delta}{\delta X_{\mu}(\sigma')}\bigg)F$$

My doubt is *why red-colored tensors are used*? I understand they are there for contracting with $X^{\mu}$  to get scalar but the diffeomorphism here is for the coordinates $(\tau, \sigma)$ so these contractions are not constrained by diff. symmetry. In flat spacetime (on worldsheet) it is given by $(3.6.3)$ $$\frac{2}{\alpha'}\int d^2z :\partial X^{\color{red}\mu}\bar{\partial}X^{\color{red}\nu} e^{ik\cdot X}:$$
the $\mu,\nu$ indices are not contracted here.

Comment: The last equation just looks like shorthand to me. You do need to contract with a polarisation tensor $P_{\mu\nu}$ - indeed, this determines the state corresponding to the vertex operator depending on whether $P_{\mu\nu}$ is traceless symmetric, antisymmetric or pure trace.